# Same phpmyadmin port for two docker containers

Tags: docker

I want to use the same phpmyadmin port and create only two different databases for two different services. Is it possible? I tried this:

docker-compose.yml for the first service

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  accounting-software:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - accounting_db
  
  accounting_db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: accounting_software
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: accounting_db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

docker-compose.yml for the second service

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  accounting-chat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    depends_on:
      - chat_db
  
  chat_db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: accounting_chat
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: chat_db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint accounting-chat_phpmyadmin_1 (6bed4e2c149b0bf6ed3079f50984c4322cb4fce6c693c3b1c92e8f29229654a7): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated`

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the last lines of the both `docker-compose` files. They both have "8080:80" ports. If you need two instances of `phpmyadmin` to be run, you should change one of them. For example change one of them to "8081:80" or maybe you can have one instance running. As you have changed chat db ports.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: accounting_db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  accounting-software:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - accounting_db
  
  accounting_db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: accounting_software
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    depends_on:
      - phpmyadmin

  

  accounting-chat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    depends_on:
      - chat_db
  
  chat_db_2:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: accounting_chat
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
    depends_on:
      - phpmyadmin
```

For more details, the first port is your local machine port and the second port is for container. As you have one unique available port on your machine, you can't another instance running on the port that has a service on it. It should be killed or changed to another port.

Comment: I want to have one instance of PHPMYADMIN is it possible?

Comment: @Alea Yeah! it's possible. Just run one of them. You can delete the second `phpmyadmin` from your docker-compose file and then find out the running images (containers) via `docker container ls` command.

Comment: But chat_db is not being created on phpmyadmin

Comment: @Alea Done. I think you can check it now!

Comment: Do I need to put this on both `docker-compose.yml` files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234484/discussion-between-mostafa-ghadimi-and-alea).